# Javascript Async/Await program order

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

```js
const function1 = () => 
      new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
          setTimeout(() => {
             resolve(10)
          },6000)
       });
       
const function2 = async () => {
    console.log("first");

    const val = await function1()
    console.log("second");
    return val
}

console.log("third -- " ,function2())
```

I was exepecting the order of the message as below:

```
first
second
third -- Promise { <pending> }>
```

But it turns out to give the below output:

```
first 
third -- Promise { <pending> }
second
```

can anyone please help me understanding this ?

Comment: You didn’t await your function2 call.

Comment: @CharlieFish, my understanding is when i am calling "function2" after it print the message "first", it should have waited for "function1" to be resolved and then should execute message "second"; but it seems like "function2" skipped that and returned an unresolved promise and later it came back and executed the message "second"

Comment: @lavender  that is exactly what is happening, because you didn't wait (or await) until the promise resolved and just logged out the pending Promise. I think this video of MPJ does a great job explaining how the confusing part of Promises work. https://youtu.be/2d7s3spWAzo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

explanation of your code

1. console.log("first"); - goes first, I hope that there is no questions
2. when interpretator see this line `const val = await function1()` - it waits here and continue to execute synchronous code with is `console.log("third -- " ,function2())` and you can see `third -- Promise { <pending> }`
3. than promise is resolving and execution of async part continues and you finally can see `console.log("second");`

to achieve expected behavior try this:

```js
const function1 = () => 
      new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
          setTimeout(() => {
             resolve(10)
          },6000)
       });
       
const function2 = async () => {
    console.log("first");

    const val = function1()
    console.log("second");
    return val
}

console.log("third -- " , function2())
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @qiAlex. Had i been use `then` instead of `await`, the message `second` would have been immediately executed. But `await` just blocks till the async code finishes, isn't it ?

Answer (score 1):

rather than calling `function2()` you need to `await` on it

```
    await function2(); // logs first (6 seconds expire) second, 10
```

this is because you need to wait for function 2 to resolve the Promise before proceeding

you could do the following for the desired result

```
    const function3 = async () => {
        const third = await function2();
        console.log( "third --", third ) 
    }
    function3();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try next code

```
const function1 = () =>
  new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(10)
    }, 6000)
  });

const function2 = async () => {
  console.log("first");

  const val = await function1()
  console.log("second");
  return val;
}

const start = async () => {
  console.log("third -- ", await function2());
};

start();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's in the logs buddy :)!

The log with the word *third* is logged second. Because the log with the word '*second*' is resolved inside function2 which is *called as a normal function*.  This code basically assumes you're not interested in the (async) result of function two, so it just retuns the pending promise.

Whenever you want the result (and not the pending promise) of an async function you should always `await` it of chain a `then()` where you can log the final result, which in this case is 10.